# 20in iMAC-iSight - 12.04 Black Screen with Mouse Icon after boot

Tags: 12.04, drivers, display, mac, powerpc

I recently installed 12.04 onto a iMAC G5 2.1 GHz PPC. The install went fine and I am able too successfully boot, however upon boot I only see a black screen with a mouse pointer.

My issue is the same as: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123510

I have tried all of the suggested boot parameters but to no avail. When I attempt to enter terminal and logon, the mouse icon goes away and I think I am logged in, however the system will not respond to any commands to force the display mode.

I believe my issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1044180, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix it given the fact I cannot see anything and the terminal commands I am attempting to do without a monitor are not working. Please help!

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Use the following yaboot parameters in this order.

```
Linux single debug nosplash b43.blacklist=yes
```

When you get to Single user mode:

- Connect cable to ethernet port and configure with `ifconfig` if needed.
- Run

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-image-powerpc64-smp
  ```
- Wait for updates to finish
- Run

  ```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```
- wait for update to finish
- Run

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Let system boot and hopefully you can see the screen and logon.